# Slow Minecraft, how to fix FPS

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

How can you speed up Minecraft FPS without using these two solutions: Optifine & Settings?

Comment: Hi - you've probably been downvoted because your question showed no original research or effort. Next time, try including more details about what went wrong and how you've tried to fix it before posting a question. Welcome to arQAde :)

Comment: Can you post your computer's specifications? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As the previous answer said, you can assign more RAM to your Minecraft (DO NOT assign all of your RAM to it, that can overload your computer), but you can also enable Advanced OpenGL.  That should drastically increase your FPS and also just make the game run more smoothly in general.

Answer (score 0):

Assign more RAM to Minecraft: [link](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1395030-tutorial-allocate-more-memory-for-minecraft/)

Comment: This only helps if minecraft is already using more than a gigabyte of ram, which it most likely isn't.